# How launch JavaScript function in every new opened tab or window of the same HTML page?

Tags: javascript

I have html page SomePage with onload event:

```
<body onload="someEvent()">
```

I attached to the SomePage js file with someEvent function:

```
function someEvent()
{
    someFunction();
}
```

When I open SomePage, the someEvent function is launching in first tab. But it not launch when I open SomePage in new tab. How relaunch js function in every new opened tab or window of the same page?

**Update:**

When I run somePage in Visual Studio witn JavaScript debugging mode and put breakpoint in someEvent function, Debugger breaking it only in first opened tab, when I open second tab, Debugger do not break the point. Therefore, I decided, that my function not refreshed in second tab. After your answers I realized that it's not JavaScript problem and my previous example work correct only without breaking point in new opened tab. Thank you for your help.

Comment: are these ON the page or other pages opened BY this page? otherwise NO.

Comment: Could you please explain more? Opening a new tab and new window should be the same, so your description of the problem should not occur.

Comment: Just describe what you actually want, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work in every tab as long as long as you are loading the same page.
You can test by making an alert call in the onLoad callback function.

```
<body onload="someEvent()">
<script>
function someEvent()
{
    alert('hi');
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please show the CODE to get the newly opened window reference

Comment: That's not possible. I assume the op is manually opening a new tab and loading the same page again.

Answer (score 1):

We may need more info on this. If you are just going to SomePage on a separate tab then anything that happened in the first tab should happen in the second. If that isn't what you are doing then the next tab is being opened by the first and that is where we need more info.

If I need to do something on load I usually set the following up in my javascript file and link it to my html page through a `<script src="/path/to/file">`

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  runFunctionAfterLoaf();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
window.onload = function() {
      someFunction();
};
```